# Unable to run Unregister-ScheduledTask via php

Tags: php, powershell, windows-task-scheduler

while creating task I used the command

```
$cmd3 = 'Register-ScheduledTask '.$ID.' -Action $action -Trigger $trigger';
$check = Shell_Exec("powershell.exe -executionpolicy bypass -NoProfile -Command " . $cmd3 . ";");
```

Now, I am trying to delete the task via this command:

```
$cmd1 = "Unregister-ScheduledTask -TaskName ". "\"".$ID."\"";
$check = Shell_Exec("powershell.exe -executionpolicy bypass -NoProfile -Command " . $cmd1 . " -Confirm:\$false;");
```

It's not getting deleted when I run the php script. So, I tried the same command on powershell and got this error:

```
Unregister-ScheduledTask : Access is denied.
At line:1 char:1
+ Unregister-ScheduledTask -TaskName 27
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : PermissionDenied: (MSFT_ScheduledT...TaskPath = "\"):Root/Microsoft/...T_ScheduledTask) [Unregister-ScheduledTask
   ], CimException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : HRESULT 0x80070005,Unregister-ScheduledTask
```

I am not sure about how I can give admin priveleges via php. Also, am I using -Confirm correctly?